# Orbeon performance by caching of js and css. How?

Tags: configuration, browser-cache, orbeon

I am using Orbeon 3.9 CE on tomcat. And also another Server runs Orbeon 3.9 CE on Weblogic for different environment.

I can see that the js file send from server is around 800Kb and the css send is around 50Kb.These files are send every time when I hit a page.
So when my form renders it takes a lot of time to download these files.

I tried to compress the files and it gave a good download advantage. as the file size reduced to 179 Kb and 10 Kb respectively.

But still I am thinking if I can cache these files in my browser cache, I could get a serious performance improvement on the time.

Please let me know how to achieve this in Orbeon.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: On the compression, that's right: you should always enable gzip compression in your servlet container or web server for HTML, JavaScript and CSS files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to deal with this is to set the `oxf.xforms.cache-combined-resources` property to `true` so those combines files are [generated on disk](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-javascript-css-resources#TOC-Configuration), and [setup an Apache front-end](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-javascript-css-resources#TOC-Examples-of-Apache-configurations) to serve those resources. Apache will be more efficient than Tomcat/Orbeon serving those files, and allows you to control the expiration date.

Now however, the downside is that if you set the expiration to be too much in the future, when JavaScript or CSS changes, either because you changed it or because you upgraded Orbeon Forms, you have a incur the risk of a browser still using an old version of the JavaScript or CSS. And if you set the expiration to be closer to the current time, browsers will reload those resources more often than they need to. To solve this conundrum, Orbeon Forms PE implements [version resources](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-javascript-css-resources#TOC-Versioned-resources) (you'll find more details following that link, if using Orbeon Forms PE is an option for you).